# Why is my server not live after deploying to Heroku?

Tags: heroku

I'm new to all of this and I finally managed to get a full deploy to Heroku from Github without it crashing. Everything says its ready to go live. I tried to start the server but it fails. It gives me an H10. Do I have to let heroku see EVERYTHING in github even when the project doesn't require such?

Comment: "Do I have to let heroku see EVERYTHING" – can you elaborate? Did you deploy the entire codebase to Heroku or some partial bit of code? What's in your Heroku app's logs? They probably tell you what you need to know to debug and fix.

Comment: It said H10 and above that a bit said a couple files that it saw missing but that the original source had intentionally git ignored and they have live

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow your wording. Post the logs, code/file structure, etc if you want help.

Comment: https://github.com/Prowlcorp/Pokemon-Showdown-VProwl
https://pastebin.com/KQxDvRGH
'cannot find config example' i have config so it shouldn't bother with that. It should see 'pokemon-showdown' and 'index.js' and it shouldn't need config loader from .*dist